# How can I DRY this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a Ruby code:

```
  if (@user.isAdmin?)
    @admin_profile         = AdminProfile.new 
    @user.admin_profile    = @admin_profile 
    @admin_profile.save
    @user.admin_profile_id = @admin_profile.id 
  else        
    @personal_profile = PersonalProfile.new
    @user.personal_profile = @personal_profile
    @personal_profile.save
    @user.personal_profile_id = @personal_profile.id
  end
```

Is it possible to DRY this code? Two code is very similar, but as you can see, they have some difference, is it possible to make it simpler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a first step you could use the same variable regardless of the profile type i.e.

```
@profile = @user.isAdmin? ? AdminProfile.new : PersonalProfile.new
```

This is using Ruby's [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) which has the form *condition* ? *value if true* : *value if false*. i.e. if `@user.isAdmin?` evaluates to `true` then `@profile` gets the value after the `?`. If `@user.isAdmin?` is false then `@profile` gets the value after the `:`. Notice that because your method name already ends in a `?` you get this appearance of a double `?`.

and then

```
if (@user.isAdmin?)
  @user.admin_profile = @profile 
  @user.admin_profile_id = @profile.id 
else        
  @user.personal_profile = @profile
  @user.personal_profile_id = @profile.id
end
```

Also, not sure if this is Rails code, but if it is then you don't need to set `admin_profile` and `admin_profile_id`, and in fact `@profile.id` won't be set yet as the profile hasn't saved. So possibly you could reduce the `if/else` to:

```
if (@user.isAdmin?)
  @user.admin_profile = @profile 
else        
  @user.personal_profile = @profile
end
```

**Update**

You should also look into the [create_association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001318) method which you get when you use a `belongs_to` association. You can have Rails create and save an associated object all in a single step e.g.

```
@user.create_personal_profile
```

Comment: sorry, I forget to save the profile, by the way, I would like to know, what the ? ? standard for... I know @user.isAdmin?, but what is the next question mark means? thank you.

Comment: @Tattat - the `?` is the [Ruby ternary operator](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/simple_constructs.html): `<condition> ? <if_true> : <if_false>`.

Comment: Updated answer with an explanation of the `?:` conditional operator and tip on also looking into the `create_association` method.

Answer (score 1):

what about this to reduce if else

@user.isAdmin? ? @user.admin_profile = @profile : @user.personal_profile = @profile